# Populate ArrayList in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I'm trying to populate a simple listview using an array of strings in ArrayList.  Every time I try though it force closes.  I know I'm getting the correct strings in the array as I've seen with Logcat.  I can't seem to figure out why it is force closing.  Maybe I'm forgetting something in ArrayAdapter (it looks correct to me) or maybe I'm putting my populate method in the wrong place... Can someone help me with this?

```
public class SchedLayout extends Activity {

public ArrayList<String> titleArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sched_layout_layout);

    new doParse().execute();
}

private class doParse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/directory/");
    File file = new File(dir, "file.html");

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    input, "UTF-8"));
            String line;
            titleArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String html = line;
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
                Elements rels = doc.select("a[rel]");
                for (Element title : rels) {
                    String exclude = "Follow";
                    if (title.attr("title").contains(exclude)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    titleArray.add(title.attr("title"));
                    // Log.v("", title.attr("title"));  <--works
                }
            }
            br.close();
            input.close();
            populate(titleArray);  <--does not work
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //Never happens
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void populate(ArrayList<String> array) {
        ListView showList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> shows = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        showList.setAdapter(shows);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your `populate` call to `onPostExecute`. You cannot modify the `ListView` in `doInBackground` or anything UI related.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
    populate(titleArray);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought I might have had that method in the wrong place.  :)